# Nature et accord de l'adjectif de couleur complexe

Tags: grammaire, adjectifs, accord, syntaxe, groupe-nominal

Les groupes nominaux selon le schéma « couleur [adjectif de couleur] » sont conçus comme les autres groupes nominaux et donc l'adjectif de couleur s'accorde avec le nom « couleur », ce qui résulte en les formes correctes « la couleur bleue », « la couleur verte » etc. et non pas  « la couleur bleu », « la couleur vert ».
Lorsque l'on change la teinte de la couleur et que l'on doit utiliser par exemple « bleu clair », « vert clair » [l'accord n'est plus fait](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=couleur+bleu+clair%2Ccouleur+bleue+claire%2Ccouleur+vert+clair%2Ccouleur+verte+claire&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccouleur%20bleu%20clair%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccouleur%20bleue%20claire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccouleur%20vert%20clair%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccouleur%20verte%20claire%3B%2Cc0) : on doit écrire « la couleur bleu clair », « la couleur vert clair ». L'ngram fourni montre qu'il existe des cas d'accord, cela étant le signe d'un certain malaise dans cette partie du système d'accord de l'adjectif.
De même, en [position d'attribut](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=est+verte+claire%2Cest+bleu+clair&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cest%20bleu%20clair%3B%2Cc0), on ne trouve pas d'accord, ce qui peut faire penser que les groupes adjectivaux de couleur n'existent pas.

- Connait-on une raison pour cette apparente incongruité ? Est-elle le résultat d'un principe grammatical connu ou doit-on l'imputer à des caprices de l'usage ?
- Comment doit on analyser cet élément dans une construction attributive  (Elle est *verte*. [adjectif attribut du sujet], Elle est *vert clair*. [adjectif ?, attribut ?]) ?
- Comment doit on analyser cet élément dans groupe nominal  (la couleur *verte* [adjectif épithète de « couleur »], la couleur  *vert clair*. [adjectif ?, épithète ?]) ?
- Les rares cas d'accord que l'on trouve dans la littérature sont-ils acceptables ? Pourquoi sont-ils tolérés ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pour la première question; si l'on ne dit pas : *une couverture bleue claire*, c'est bien parce que c'est le bleu qui est clair, pas la couverture.

> Si, pour désigner la couleur, on emploie un adjectif qualifié par un autre adjectif ou complété par un nom, l'ensemble reste invariable, parce que le premier adjectif est substantivement, et suppose l'ellipse de "un": "Des yeux **bleu clair**" (= d'un bleu clair). (Grevisse, *Le Bon usage*, 7e éd., 1959, 380 b).

Le même raisonnement vaut pour les couleurs qui sont des noms (comme marron, orange, poivre et sel), puisqu'il y a ellipse (selon Grevisse, *id.*, 381) de l'expression "de la couleur de" (de la couleur du marron).

Quant à certaines couleurs composées (bleu et blanc), il faut noter qu'il y a nuance de sens entre : des robes bleu et blanc et des robes bleues et blanches. Là encore, la question est : est-ce la couleur qui est composée pour chaque robe (donc pas d'accord) ou l'ensemble des robes qui comporte des robes bleues et d'autres blanches (donc accord). Grevisse n'évoque rien de tel dans cette édition, mais je me range à l'avis de Girodet :

> Invariabilité quand on veut indiquer que la chose décrite est de deux
>   (ou plusieurs) couleurs [...] *des autobus jaune et vert*. L'accord
>   *des autobus jaunes et verts* signifierait qu'il y a des autobus jaunes et d'autres verts. (*Pièges et Difficultés de la langue
>   française*, 1988, Annexe : Les adjectifs de couleur, 2).

Answer (score 3):

Question 1 : Pas à ma connaissance.

Question 2 : Il peut y avoir plusieurs adjectifs attributs pour un sujet.

Question 3 : Il peut y avoir plusieurs adjectifs épithètes liés.

Questions 4 : La règle grammaticale est claire, les rares cas trouvés sont biens des fautes. Après, savoir si une faute est acceptable dépend de tout un chacun. Est-ce que tu trouves inacceptable qu'Alphonse Daudet ait écrit "*housse de sparterie bleue et blanche*". À toi de juger. Par contre c'est une faute.

Pourquoi sont-elles tolérées? Une fois publiées que veux-tu faire? Demander aux auteurs de faire un mea culpa et d'aller corriger fissa tous les livres parus? Une fois que la faute est faite et publiée elle fait partie de l'œuvre et il n'y a plus qu'à composer avec.

Comment: La raison pour ces fautes qui se glissent dans le matériel imprimé serait donc  un manque de responsabilité des éditeurs qui n'emploieraient pas de personnel de révision assez qualifié plutôt qu'une tolérance par ce personnel qui serait fondée sur des principes grammaticaux connus. Il me semblait qu'un ouvrage prêt à paraitre était  toujours auparavant soigneusement vérifié,  en particulier dans le travail appelé la correction des épreuves. (champ 1)

Comment: Je suis bien en peine de voir cette faute, « housse» et « sparterie » sont du féminin ; que l'accord se fasse avec l'un ou l'autre (ce de quoi on ne peut pas être sûr) il  semble correct !  Je ne crois pas en ce critère d'acceptabilité ; un critère que je serais prêt à considérer serait celui de théories grammaticales concurrentes, pas celui des fantaisies de tout un chacun.(fin)

Comment: @LPH Il ne s'agit pas d'une fantaisie, la plupart des grammairiens recommandent l'absence d'accord et donc d'écrire *housse de sparterie bleu et blanc*. cf. [oqlf1](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1724) et [oqlf2](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1725)

Comment: Un ouvrage à paraître est toujours soigneusement vérifié. Au vu de la quantité d'ouvrages publiés par an, le nombre d'erreurs qui passent les corrections sans être corrigées est infime.

Comment: Dans l'idéal, oui, dans les faits, c'est beaucoup moins vrai, et s'y collent souvent des personnes qui ont déjà travaillé le texte auparavant (ce qui est une très mauvaise idée) : éditeur, préparateur de copie, etc. La méthode plus traditionnelle dans laquelle l'auteur écrit, l'éditeur commente et fait récrire, le préparateur de copie vérifie, source, émonde et amende, puis le ou les correcteurs corrigent successivement les épreuves, est de plus ou plus rare.