# Why not "grise" in "une fourrure gris clair"?

Tags: adjectifs

Since fourrure is female I would expect "une fourrure grise claire" but my text book says "gris clair", why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a color is made up of more than one word, the adjective is invariable and does not change according to the noun as you would expect.

For example, les yeux bleus would be les yeux bleu ciel.

More information: l'accord de l'adjectif de couleur in [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33653/nature-et-accord-de-ladjectif-de-couleur-complexe/34802#34802).

Answer (score 2):

It's a rule: when the adjective is a compound there is no agreement ([Obs](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/regles/orthographe/l-accord-de-l-adjectif-de-couleur-2.php)).

Comment: There are some adjectives other than colours that do work like this as well, but I believe it would be preferable to state explicitely that this answer concerns colours and not all adjectives (some examples where the rule, stated as it stands now, wouldn’t apply: des sourds-muets, des morts-vivants, une zone climatique subtropicale humide).